# Use same label for different nodes in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using section 5 "Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs" of the TikZ manual to draw syntax diagrams in LaTeX. One issue I'm facing however, is that I want to use the same label for different nodes, but the rendered image always has the arrows pointing towards the first node that uses that name. Sample code is as follows:

```
\tikz [>=stealth', black!50, text=black, thick,
   every new ->/.style          = {shorten >=1pt},
   graphs/every graph/.style    = {edges=rounded corners},
   skip loop/.style             = {to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
   hv path/.style               = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
   vh path/.style               = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
   nonterminal/.style           = {
     rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick, draw=red!50!black!50, top color=white,
     bottom color=red!50!black!20, font=\itshape, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex},
   terminal/.style              = {
     rounded rectangle,  minimum size=6mm, very thick, draw=black!50, top color=white,
     bottom color=black!20, font=\ttfamily, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
   shape                        = coordinate
   ]       
\graph [grow right sep, branch down=7mm, simple] {
/ -> "def"[nonterminal] ->[vh path]
{[nodes={yshift=7mm}]
  "resource-type"[terminal] -> "name"[nonterminal], 
  "resource"[terminal]  -> "resource-type.name"[nonterminal] -> "name"[nonterminal],
  "resource-type-attribute"[nonterminal] -> "resource-type.name"[nonterminal],
  "resource-attribute"[nonterminal],
  "resource-type-relationship"[nonterminal] -> "resource-type.name 1"[nonterminal] -> "name"[nonterminal] -> "resource-type.name 2"[nonterminal],
  "resource-relationship"[nonterminal]
}
```

};

Comment: Why do you "want to use the same label for different nodes"?

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn because I'm describing a syntax and it makes sense for nodes with different labels to appear in different places. For example in a simple programming languages a "variable" could appear in a variety of different contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read page 268 in [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) where how to distinguish between `node's text` and `node's name` is explained.

`"name"[nonterminal]` declares a `nonterminal` type node named `name` and with `name` as node contents. If you repeat the command later on, `graphs` library doesn't creates a new node but uses the previously created one.

If you want to have different nodes with same contents but different name, you can use `name1[as=name, nonterminal]` which declares a node named `name1` but with contents `name`. Later on you can use `name2[as=name, nonterminal]` which will declare a new node (`name2`)  with same contents.

What I think you want is:

[image]

And the code to get it is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,graphs,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', black!50, text=black, thick,
   every new ->/.style          = {shorten >=1pt},
   graphs/every graph/.style    = {edges=rounded corners},
   skip loop/.style             = {to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
   hv path/.style               = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
   vh path/.style               = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
   nonterminal/.style           = {
     rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick, draw=red!50!black!50, top color=white,
     bottom color=red!50!black!20, font=\itshape, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex},
   terminal/.style              = {
     rounded rectangle,  minimum size=6mm, very thick, draw=black!50, top color=white,
     bottom color=black!20, font=\ttfamily, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex},
   shape                        = coordinate
   ]       
\graph [grow right sep, branch down=7mm, simple] {
/ -> "def"[nonterminal] ->[vh path]
{[nodes={yshift=7mm}]
  "resource-type"[terminal] -> "name1"[as=name, nonterminal], 
  "resource"[terminal]  -> "resource-type.name"[nonterminal] -> "name2"[as=name,nonterminal],
  "resource-type-attribute"[nonterminal] -> "resource-type.name2"[as=resource-type.name, nonterminal],
  "resource-attribute"[nonterminal],
  "resource-type-relationship"[nonterminal] -> "resource-type.name 1"[nonterminal] -> "name3"[as=name, nonterminal] -> "resource-type.name 2"[nonterminal],
  "resource-relationship"[nonterminal]
}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dirty trick: Add some useless code to make the content different. Such as

```
%! TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes, graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners, >=Stealth, auto]
  \graph[layered layout, nodes={draw}]{%
    "a" -> "a$ $" -> "$ $a" -> "$ $a$ $";
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You will see 4 `a` not one `a`.